# enable facebook comment in android app

Tags: javascript, android, html, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am developing a android app in which it loads the article which is of HTML Content in the **WebView**

Now the requirement is

Every single article needs a **facebook** comment part at last of article

- for the viewers to give comments
- for viewing the comments

Before applying this to app i did for website and its working perfectly fine(can see the comment at bottom of the page)
http://rapideinfotech.com/testing/ankur/

**Problem Statement:**
The comment plugin is not enabled in the article. How do I fix this?

For getting app ID i have followed the steps in this link
[for appid](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android)

i am  loading the article in the webview via htmldata

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style = text/css>
     img {
          width:100%!important;
          height:auto!important;
         } 
     iframe {
          width:100sp;
          max-height:100sp;
          } 
     a { 
          color:#3366CC; 
          text-decoration: none; 
       } 
     </style> 
     <body style = 'line-height:25px;' >
       <script>
       (function(d, s, id) 
       { 
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) return; 
         js = d.createElement(s); 
         js.id = id; 
         js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=576245362521056&version=v2.0'; 
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         }
         (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
      "+c+" 
     <div id=\"fb-root\"></div> 
     <div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\""+p+"\" data-numposts=\"5\" data-colorscheme=\"light\">                                                    </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

- "c" is the variable which has article content
- "p" is the variable which has the article link

Comment: do you mean something like this?
[comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments)

Comment: @EdanFeiles thanks, im stuck in using this while implementing,i dont know use that code

Answer (score 0):

To Create the Facebook comments plugin you need:

1) Create a facebook app [android-facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android).

2) Copy and paste the following code to the beginning of the `<body>` section (JavaScript SDK):

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOURAPPIDHERE&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

3) Replace `YOUR-APPID-HERE` with your app id from [facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com) apps tab (select the app you just created).

4) Add the following code to the bottom of the article or where ever you want to:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="URL OF THE ARTICLE" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

5) Replace `URL OF THE ARTICLE` with the url of the page the article is in.

Comment: i have edited the same post about the problem occurring kindly help me Edan to solve this struggling from last whole night

Comment: post the URL of the page loaded by webview.

Comment: ya that hyperlink is in the variable name "p"

Comment: i mean, give me here the URL so i will see the page loaded in webview. i need to see the generated page.

Comment: @madhavan what's the problem?
i see the comments plugin in the bottom.

Comment: can u send the app screenshot because its not showing here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65123/discussion-between-madhavan-and-edan-feiles).